# How can i delete items from a list in JavaScript by clicking?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a grocery list and i want individual items to be added and also deleted. How can this be done?

```js
function getValue() {
  var val = document.getElementById("itemList").value;
  var list = document.getElementById("demo");
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  var addList = document.createTextNode(val);
  element.appendChild(addList);
  list.prepend(element);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Common List </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="itemList">
    <button type="button" onclick="getValue()">add to list</button>
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add an event listener to `element` that calls `this.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the element when you add it. This can use the `remove()` method to remove it from the list.

```js
function getValue() {
  var val = document.getElementById("itemList").value;
  var list = document.getElementById("demo");
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  var addList = document.createTextNode(val);
  element.appendChild(addList);
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (confirm(`Do you really want to remove ${this.innerText}`)) {
      this.remove();
    }
  });
  list.prepend(element);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Common List </title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="itemList">
    <button type="button" onclick="getValue()">add to list</button>
    <ul id="demo"></ul>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Items are actually removed by clicking.